# iOS app for toggling bluetooth when iPhone is plugged into dock

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, bluetooth, power

Are there any apps that will toggle bluetooth on/off when the phone is plugged or unplugged from power?

I only use bluetooth in my car when it is plugged in the dock so that is the only time I would like it turned on. I've searched the App Market and haven't found anything. Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask what your reason is for wanting to do this? 

The most common reason for turning Bluetooth off would be be to save power, which is unnecessary when you are plugged in.

Is it because your device can still connect to a Bluetooth device in the car when you are docked? (I have had that problem myself as my desk is close to there the car is parked)

Answer (score 1):

Not without Jailbraking. App-Store restrictions prevent any application developers from changing hardware settings. You can always suggest a feature to Apple by visiting http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html